# Beginner: When working with arrays, why does this work but not this?

Tags: arrays, swift

The one with `colorsArray.last` works but not the one with the subscript syntax, e.g., `colorsArray[2]`. Any help you can give me with understanding this would be great. I'm learning Swift on my own so I come here to get my questions answered.

```
let colorsArray = ["Red", "Green", "Blue"]


if let method2 = colorsArray.last {
    print(method2)
}


if let method2 = colorsArray[2] {
    print(method2)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that with an array, the subscript operator does not return an [optional](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330), so it makes no sense to use an unwrapping construct like `if let` to unwrap it.

Try `let foo = colorsArray[42]`, where the index is out of bounds. It doesn’t return `nil`, but rather will just crash with an “subscript out of range” error. As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array) says (emphasis added):

> Use the `first` and `last` properties for *safe access* to the value of the array’s first and last elements. If the array is empty, these properties are `nil`.
>
> ...
>
> You can access individual array elements through a subscript. The first element of a nonempty array is always at index zero. You can subscript an array with any integer from zero up to, but not including, the count of the array. Using a negative number or an *index equal to or greater than count triggers a runtime error*.

So, the `last` provides safe access, returning an optional, but the subscript operator doesn’t return an optional, but also doesn’t provide safe access if you supply an invalid index.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `last` the result of subscribing an array by index is not an optional.

```
let method2 = colorsArray[2]
print(method2)
```

<strike>The reason is most likely the ObjC compatibility,</strike> the disadvantage is if the index doesn't exist it throws an exception aka it crashes.

Comment: I don't think it's compatibility. That's just expected behavior.

Comment: Yeah, it's not compatibility, it's an optimization for performance. https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/commonly_proposed.md#strings-characters-and-collection-types

Answer (score 2):

If you will go to the documentation, you will find that when you use the Api `last`, the return type is optional, hence you can use optional binding to safely unwrap the value. But if you access the element by index like you are doing in the second case will give you the unwrapped value and compiler assumes that there will be a value for sure if you access like that. But keep in mind if your array size is less than the index you are passing then you may get error of array index out of bounds.